# Gradle: how to specify outputdirectory for test-ng from command line?

Tags: gradle, testng

I am using `gradle` to run `testng` tests. In gradle script one can override the output directory like this:

```
test {
  useTestNG {
    outputDirectory = file("$buildDir/testngoutput")
  }
}
```

What I really want is to override this output directory which is needed when I use `-Dtest.single`. So far, I have tried this but it is not working:

```
gradle -Dtest.single=MyClass -DoutputDirectory=build/testng-reports-outputdirectory1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
test {
    useTestNG {
        def dir = System.getProperty("outputDirectory") 
        outputDirectory = dir ? file(dir) : file("$buildDir/testngoutput")
    }
}
```

Then call with:

```
gradle -DoutputDirectory=some/dir
```